# How to pass a variable from external javascript file to a cshtml page?

Tags: javascript, razor

I have external js file and an cshtml page. i want to return a value from js file to cshtml .. how this possible ?

Comment: Why do you want to do that on the Razor level? It would be much easier to include and use in Javascript.

Comment: becuase in external js file there is a function called sample(). i need to check whether the function is called successfully.. when function call entered in function i need to set a checking flag.. based on that i have added a condition in cshtml page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a **hidden input** tag in *cshtml* and put the **Model value** in it

cshtml:

```
<input type="hidden" id="Test" value="@Model.id" />
```

Then use that tag(*hidden input*) in your **External JS**

External JS:

```
var id=$("#Test").val();
```